# MongoDB 2.6.6 crashed with "Invalid access at address"

Tags: mongodb, segmentation-fault

Running MongoDB on my company's QA env, I ran into this error in the log:

```
2015-02-22T04:48:06.194-0500 [rsHealthPoll] SEVERE: Invalid access at address: 0
2015-02-22T04:48:06.290-0500 [rsHealthPoll] SEVERE: Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
Backtrace:0xf62526 0xf62300 0xf6241f 0x7fc70b581710 0xca12c2 0xca14e7 0xca3bb6 0xf02995 0xefb6d8 0xf9af1c 0x7fc70b5799d1 0x7fc70a2d28fd 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x26) [0xf62526]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xf62300]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xf6241f]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710) [0x7fc70b581710]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21ReplSetHealthPollTask12tryHeartbeatEPNS_7BSONObjEPi+0x52) [0xca12c2]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21ReplSetHealthPollTask17_requestHeartbeatERNS_13HeartbeatInfoERNS_7BSONObjERi+0xf7) [0xca14e7]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21ReplSetHealthPollTask6doWorkEv+0x96) [0xca3bb6]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo4task4Task3runEv+0x25) [0xf02995]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13BackgroundJob7jobBodyEv+0x128) [0xefb6d8]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xf9af1c]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x79d1) [0x7fc70b5799d1]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fc70a2d28fd]
```

It seems there's some segmentation fault in `rsHealthPoll`.

This is from a mongod instance running as part of a replica set in a shard-ready cluster (2 mongods + 1 arbiter running with config servers and mongos processes).

This DB mostly receives writes of new records, periodically updating a boolean to True for some records, and some reads, according to user activity querying it. (Single collection at the moment)

Googling this error only gave me other, older, already-solved segmentation fault bugs in MongoDB Jira.

Anyone seen this recently or knows the reason?

Comment: Can you turn up the logging (`mongod -vvvvv`) and reproduce? Which replica set member type crashes?

Comment: Something like systemLog.verbosity: 4 in the config file?

Comment: Yeah, that's corresponding YAML option.

Comment: Ok, it's up and running with more verbose logs for almost 24h. Let's hope this reproduces...